# Security of SSL Pinning

Tags: ios, security, ssl

I have an iOS app which implements SSL Pinning. I compare the remote certificate against the locally stored certificate and proceed depending on the result of the comparison. If both certificates are equal, the URL connection is permitted. Otherwise, it is denied. My question is this: **Can an attacker change the local certificate stored in the app (.ipa) with another certificate?**
This would allow the attacker to see all of my requests and responses.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but only on jailbroken device, since on non-jailbroken device you can't view the content of the installed application.

Comment: How to prevent the attacker then? Will public key pinning prevent it?

Comment: I think like an option you can keep the contents of the *.cert file in some variable and use that in your code. You can add more security by encrypting contents before keeping into a variable, and decrypt while reading it